# Chrome brings the integer value for $('.abc').css("top");

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following javascript code returns two different values for Chrome and Firefox for the same page element.

```
$('.abc').css("top");
```

Chrome returns: **114px**
while Firefox returns **114.1230px**

I've tried this several times on the same page and Chrome consistently chops off the decimal point and the following digits.

Any suggestions on how I can get the full value within Chrome as well?

Comment: I wonder if Chrome is returning the true value (how can you have 0.123 of a pixel?) whereas Firefox is returning the value you have set in css?

Comment: Related I think: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571035/computed-width-with-decimal-values-in-firefox-but-without-decimals-in-webkit.

Comment: And this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4308989/are-the-decimal-places-in-a-css-width-respected

Comment: decimal pixels could hypothetically be useful when zooming/resizing a page.  The iPhone 4, for example, doubles all CSS sizes to make older pages look good on its high resolution screen (that's going to work well going forward...), so 1 css pixel is actual 2x2 screen pixels.  .5 css pixels would theoretically be an actual screen pixel.  (Though I'd guess mobile safari does the same rounding chrome does)

Comment: You are correct but it is the job of the device to correct properties for PPI adjustment, not the programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox is a little special in this case... it supports decimal pixels. This means that if you set a height OR width on f.e. an image, it will resize the picture and this calculation will contain (most likely) decimal pixels. This is the same with divs, it gets calculated and decimals are used in firefox.

As far as I know, firefox is the only major browser that support decimals...

If you need full pixels, try a regex expression or something to remove the decimals if you have a string or `floor()` if you have a number.

Comment: Thank you. Math.floor() helped me equalize both browsers. Good explanation on how firefox behaves different.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `$('.abc').offset().top` or  `$('.abc').position().top`.

(Although what 0.123 of a pixel looks like is beyond me).

Answer (score 0):

Best answer might be to simply `floor()` the value so you end up with 114px in both cases. (Chrome rounds down the sub-pixel amount)

Comment: The OP might *want* the decimal places.

Comment: Well, Chrome rounds them down. We don't have screens that render at the sub-pixel level yet, so the decimals are useless.

Comment: No, I disagree. Try playing with `font-size` on Firefox.

Comment: Typography sizing is entirely different. Read http://style.cleverchimp.com/font_size_intervals/altintervals.html for more on font rendering.

Comment: My point is that Chrome doesn't support sub-pixel values to be stored at all, yet sub-pixel values do make a difference. BTW, I don't seem to see how that article is relevant...

Comment: Expressing a font size in pixels is completely different than expressing a div in pixels. Font size pixels are not in a relationship to on-screen pixels like a div would be. Sub pixel values only make a difference if you are expressing a decimal value as a PERCENTAGE of something else. (Like a font, or `width: 30.5%`) In the latter case, it would simply become `315px` as computed by the browser.

Comment: Yes of course it works. It gets scaled as a percentage. Your screen is not, however, magically rendering at a higher ppi. Either way, I'm not sure what your point is. Expressing font size as a decimal pixel is a travesty.

Answer (score 0):

As long as you keep the width a decimal, Chrome will truncate it. If you make it a percentage, though, (might not be an option for you), Chrome will keep it the way it is.

This might not be what you're looking for, but you can store the pixel value in the jQuery object:

```
$('#foo').data('actualTop', 114.123);
```

But why do those decimal places bother you?